# nested loop list comprehension in python ; can't recognize variable in outer loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

```
def  maxXor( l,  r):
return max(a^b for b in range(a,r+1) for a in range(l,r+1))
```

The error shows NameError: global name 'a' is not defined.

I think the error is `range(a,r+1)`

Here I want the 'a' in `range(a,r+1)` reference 'a' in the inner loop `for a in range(l,r+1))`.

Comment: Switch the order of your for-loops.

Comment: You're missing the [square brackets] for the nested list comprehensions.

This does the trick:

    def maxXor( l,  r):
         return max([[a^b for b in range(a,r+1)] for a in range(l,r+1)])

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thanks. I misunderstood the order.

Comment: @matiu When the list is a para in function, actually the square brackets could be omit. Problem solved by Steven. Also thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def  maxXor( l,  r):
    return max(a^b  for a in range(l,r+1) for b in range(a,r+1))
```